# How to remove an element from a bash array without flattening the array

Tags: bash

I would like to make a function that takes a bash array like this one:

```
a=("element zero" "element one" "element two")
```

and removes one element like "element one" and leaves a the array like this:

```
a=("element zero" "element two")
```

such that `echo $a[1]` will print out `element two` and not `zero`.

I've seen several attempts at this, but haven't found one that did it cleanly or without breaking elements that have spaces into multiple elements. Or just setting the element to be blank (i.e. not shifting the indexes of subsequent array elements).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
# initial state
a=( "first element" "second element" "third element" )

# to remove
unset a[0]

# to reindex, such that a[0] is the old a[1], rather than having the array
# start at a[1] with no a[0] entry at all
a=( "${a[@]}" )

# to print the array with its indexes, to check its state at any stage
declare -p a
```

...now, for a function, if you have bash 4.3, you can use namevars to do this without any `eval` at all:

```
remove() {
  local -n _arr=$1      # underscore-prefixed name to reduce collision likelihood
  local idx=$2
  unset _arr[$idx]      # remove the undesired item
  _arr=( "${_arr[@]}" ) # renumber the indexes
}
```

For older versions of bash, it's a bit stickier:

```
remove() {
  local cmd
  unset "$1[$2]"
  printf -v cmd '%q=( "${%q[@]}" )' "$1" "$1" && eval "$cmd"
}
```

The use of `printf` with `%q` format strings is a bit of paranoia -- it makes it harder for maliciously chosen values (in this case, variable names) to perform actions of their choice, as opposed to simply failing with no effect.

---

All that said -- it's better if you **don't** renumber your arrays. If you leave off the renumbering step, such that after deleting entry `a[1]` you simply have a sparse array with no content at that index *(which is different from an empty string at that index -- bash "arrays" are actually stored as linked lists or hash tables [in the associative case], not as arrays at all, so sparse arrays are memory-efficient)*, the delete operation is much faster.

This doesn't break your ability to iterate over your arrays if you retrieve ask the array for its keys rather than supplying them externally, as in:

```
for key in "${!a[@]}"; do
  value="${a[$key]}"
  echo "Entry $key has value $value"
done
```

Comment: Is the order of keys in "${!a[@]}" guaranteed to still be numerically increasing after elements have been unset? (I mean, to the extent that `bash` carries guarantees :) )

Comment: For a non-associative array, yes.

Comment: Charles, for your non-function example, after `unset a[0]` and reindex I get `declare -a a='([0]="second" [1]="element" [2]="third" [3]="element")'` Is there something needed to prevent word splitting on reindex? That is the output of `declare -p a`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy testing, I find you need `a=( "${a[@]}" )` to prevent word splitting.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, indeed, one does. Where do I say, imply, or demonstrate anything contrary?

Comment: It is funny how the mind plays tricks on one as we get older. I could have sworn I copied `a=( ${a[@]} )` into my command line from your answer originally... :-)

Comment: @rici, ...that said, are you using the keys at all? If you only want to iterate over values, you can use `for value in "${a[@]}"; do` and be done with it -- with, again, an assurance of ordering for the non-associative case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I was just curious, and you seem to be a reliable source of information.

Comment: Array index arguments to `unset` should be quoted (e.g. `unset 'a[0]'`).  See [Bash Pitfalls #57 (unset unquoted array element)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#unset_a.5B0.5D).  I learned this one the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove() { 
    eval "$1=( \"\${$1[@]:0:$2}\" \"\${$1[@]:$(($2+1))}\" )" 
}
```

Can be called like this:

```
a=("element zero" "element one" "element two")
remove a 1
echo ${a[@]}  #element zero element two
echo ${a[1]}  #element two
```

This will leave blank array elements.

```
a=("element zero" "element one" "" "element three")
remove a 1
echo ${a[@]}  #element zero element two
echo ${a[1]}  #
echo ${a[2]}  #element three
```

This will flatten unset elements in sparse arrays.