# JSON for command-line arguments

Tags: json, command-line, scripting

Supposed I want to write a tool, that needs to accept slightly-structured data, is it reasonable to use json for command-line arguments, and while at it, environment?

For example

```
fudge_files "['file1', 'file2']"  # here list of files could be used
fudge_files --dirs "['dir1', 'dir2']" pattern.* another*.foo
```

Or in a more convoluted example

```
fudge_files --dst "{'txt': ['/foo', '/bar'], 'pdf': ['/foo']}" pattern.*
```

Is this a good or bad idea?

What are the pitfalls?

Answer (score 1):

Most (all) shells will see the single and dbl quotes and process them per their standard procedures.

To keep the quotes so they get passed in as data, you'll need to escape them, i.e.

```
\"[\'file1\', \'file2\']\"
```

Once your data starts containing legitimate "\" chars, it gets really ugly. You can come up with hacks, but it will be painful and you can spend a **lot** of time trying debug issues related to this sort of quoting.

AND, if you persist, and make it work, then, 2-3 months later, you may think "I can put some of this in variables and use `eval`" or other craziness to expand the variable into a string. Now you're really in for a debug nightmare.

Also, I did quick test using shell ANSI strings to see if that would help, but

```
$ var=$'"['file1', 'file2']"'
$ echo $var
"[file1, file2]"
$ echo "$var"
"[file1, file2]"
$ var=$""['file1', 'file2']""
-ksh: file2]: not found [No such file or directory]
```

ANSI Strings are strings defined like `$'My Static ANSI String'` or `$"myANSIString with $var input"`
Note how in even the first example, the shell matched the single quotes at the first opportunity, and stripped them out of your input string. Hoping that it was the `echo` that was stripping them, I used best practice on the 2nd `echo` line an surrounded `"$var"` in quotes. Nope, single-quotes are gone. :-(

I don't have that much experience working with ANSI strings, so others may offer a solution that will keep the single and dbl quotes intact.

Otherwise, I don't see this working.

---

Your work flow isn't quite clear, but guessing that something is emitting these values (I hope you're not having to type them), I think you're much better off getting them into a file. If a separate program is printing them to the terminal, then just redirect into a file

```
  json_emitting_program --args .... > $tmpFile
```

Or use the Unix tool designed to elimiate tmp files, the pipe `|`, and write your tool to read its data from std-in, rather that as command-line arguments.

Then you would say either

```
  json_emitting_program --args .... | fudge_files
```

OR, using a tmp file

```
fudge_files < "$tmpFile"
```

If the source of your data is in a a MS Windows output (for instance), you can create temp files on-the-file using Unix `here-documents`, something like

```
 cat - > $tmpFile << EOS
 paste your input here
 and here
 etc
 EOS
```

Note that EOS has to be on a line of it's own, with no trailing white-space.

The shell should return the prompt to you if done it correctly.

Confirm that file is there and up-to-date

```
 ls -l $tmpFile
```

and the as above, run  your program

```
fudge_files < "$tmpFile"
```

In case you don't know, you create tmpFile with a simple assignment to any path/file you care to name:

```
tmpFile=/path/to/myTempFile
```

IHTH

Comment: Good point about complex argument reuse in shell scripts. I'm a little confused by your example `$'"[...]"'` which has an extra layer of quotes; also by your assertion that all quotes must be escaped. Isn't using different quotes for escape and content enough?

Comment: yes, the `$'"[...]"'` example is an advanced feature of the shell (ANSI strings which has 2 forms, `$'..str.'` and `$".strW$vars."`). Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of experience with them, except that I know the examples I've included are valid. My point there is that when using the `$'...'` form, the interior single quotes from your example string are then lost AND with the `$'"..."' from of ANSI strings, your sample string will cause an error when the shell tries to evaluate that line.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436988/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-bash-array-without-flattening-the-array/25437057#25437057 for a write-up on the bash shells version of `printf` and its feature `"%q` which might help you. ....BUT ... Again, trying to read strings like that on the command line is the wrong approach. Spend your time getting `fudge_files` so it can read from std-in, (pipe, or redirection) and you'll have a much more flexible and stable solution. ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @qarma : are you my any chance trying to send data via `curl`? I see lot of similar queries about `json` and `curl` and the command-line here on S.O. Basically `curl -X POST --data @/path/to/dataFile ${URL}` might help. Good luck.

Comment: in a weird twist of fate, curl or as the case may be `requests` is ultimately involved. However this structured data is not sent verbatim. My tools will actually use this data to map objects in file system, convert it to a custom format, etc. Idea is to have uniform API for a set of tools.